# How to set add question capability for author role in wp pro quiz plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, user-roles, author

[Wp pro quiz](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/) has no option to let other user roles to add and edit quizzes and questions other than admin.

In the [lib/helper/WpProQuiz_Helper_Upgrade.php](http://lib/helper/WpProQuiz_Helper_Upgrade.php) I saw this code,

```
 private static function install()
{
    $role = get_role('administrator');

    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_show');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_add_quiz');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_edit_quiz');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_delete_quiz');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_show_statistics');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_reset_statistics');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_import');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_export');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_change_settings');
    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_toplist_edit');

    //ACHIEVEMENTS Version 2.x.x
    if (defined('ACHIEVEMENTS_IS_INSTALLED') && ACHIEVEMENTS_IS_INSTALLED === 1 && defined('ACHIEVEMENTS_VERSION')) {
        $version = ACHIEVEMENTS_VERSION;
        if ($version{0} == '2') {
            WpProQuiz_Plugin_BpAchievementsV2::install();
        }
    }
} 
  private static function updateV19()
{
    $role = get_role('administrator');

    $role->add_cap('wpProQuiz_toplist_edit');
}
```

So, I decided to replace 'administrator' with 'author' to let the author roles to use this plugin.

But it didn't work. Do i need to do anything further.

Answer (score 0):

A much more efficient way that doesn't require editing the source code:

install and activate [wpfront User role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/%22Wpfront's%20User%20role%20editor%22),

go to all roles,

edit the author role,

scroll down to the 'other capabilities' section,

check the following capabilities: wpProQuiz_show, wpProQuiz_add_quiz, wpProQuiz_edit_quiz
Save.

The authors on your site should now be able to add and edit quizes.

Comment: I do this , but users  can see all quiz , and can edit other user quiz!! can change this? any user should see his quiz only

Comment: You do not have to add all the options suggested above. Play with them and use only the options that give you what you want.

Comment: options suggested above just show wpproquiz in menu , but not set permission on quizzes. for example user a create quiz. user b after login see all quiz !!!! it means user b can edit or delete user a quiz.